# Can't obtain Outlook.Application while Outlook is running until a non-Outlook window is in the foreground

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop, com-interop

`Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application")` throws `Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))` when Outlook is started and continues while it is running until a non-Outlook window becomes the active foreground window.

I am running Outlook Version 1901 Build 11231.20130 on Windows 10 Version 1803 Build 17134.523 (this is my local machine). I've observed client machines that do not behave this way. This is occurring in a WPF application using .NET 4.5.2 and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook version 15.0.4797.1003 obtained via NuGet.

I have repeatedly run the following code. As detailed above, it will succeed once an instance of Outlook has been minimized or a non-Outlook window is set to the foreground, but it can continuously fail (output below) before this has occurred. I have tried to pause for ~20-30 seconds to give Outlook time to load but still get the same result.

```
    // Detect that the active window is an Outlook window
    Outlook.Application app = null;
    // Optional: Wait for Outlook to load 20-30 sec using Thread.Sleep
    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("app");
        app = (Outlook.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
        Debug.WriteLine("got app");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }
    // Do things with app
```

While Outlook is running, I expect to see:

```
app
got app
```

which occurs if a non-Outlook window set to the foreground (i.e. not an Explorer or an Inspector window) since Outlook has started. If Outlook is running and has always been in the foreground, I instead see:

```
app
Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))
```

As a shot in the dark, I've tried to "boot up" Interop by doing the following when I notice this occurring:

```
bootApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
```

To no effect. Any input would be valued. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible that Outlook is run as one user (say your user) and the application as another user (for example as administrator)?

Comment: I'm not the original poster, but I have the same problem. I've tried running both Outlook and the application as administrator and this problem still persists. I still get `{"Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))"}`

Comment: @ThomasZhang If you just use `new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();`, can you work on that instance? Interop should give you the already running application

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm not sure. Note that if I leave the program running and minimize Outlook's Explorer, for example, I will suddenly have access to the `Outlook.Application`.

Comment: @Shroom Can you use the `bootApplication` after newing it up?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes, I've successfuly acquired `bootApplication` and `bootApplication.Session` thereafter, but I am still seeing the same result with `app`. So the output looks like:
 `// Exception getting app; bootApplication; got bootApplication; session; got session; app; // Exception getting app`

Comment: @Shroom So why don't you just use `bootApplication`?

Comment: I'm using `ActiveWindow` of the user, and so forth.

Comment: I see what you're saying from Dmitry's comment below. Thank you Camilo!

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/238610/getobject-or-getactiveobject-cannot-find-a-running-office-application

Comment: Thanks Hans, but that's not why I was receiving the exception. As noted above, I experimented with sleeping the thread to ensure that Outlook had time to stabilize. The issue is that Marshal shouldn't be used here, as noted in the solution below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `GetActiveObject` with Outlook - it is a singleton, so creating a new instance of the `Outlook.Application` object will return a pointer to the existing instance if it is already running.

Comment: I'm assuming this means it makes no sense to call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` on `app` either, but I will still have to do this for each com object I access via `app`. Is that correct?

Comment: It won't hurt, and you need to be careful with multiple dot notation since its creates implicit variables that cannot be explicitly released.

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact the documented behaviour, which Microsoft say is 'optimized' and 'by design':

> When an Office application starts, it does not immediately register its running objects. This optimizes the application's startup process. Instead of registering at startup, an Office application registers its running objects in the ROT once it loses focus. Therefore, if you attempt to use GetObject or GetActiveObject to attach to a running instance of an Office application before the application has lost focus, you might receive one of the errors above.

The quotations are from [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/getobject-or-getactiveobject-cannot-find-a-running-office-application-6cdf21a3-ac90-512b-6bff-badc5f4cc215)<sup>([archive 1](http://web.archive.org/web/20221002065543/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/getobject-or-getactiveobject-cannot-find-a-running-office-application-6cdf21a3-ac90-512b-6bff-badc5f4cc215), [archive 2](https://archive.is/wip/3aYTN))</sup> support page.

As a workaround they suggest flipping focus to another window:

> Using code, you can change focus from the Office application to your own application (or to some other application)